# sinch tutorial showspinner() problems

Tags: android, sinch

and trying to make a chat app using sinch and parse follow the tutorial and review the github code from the search tutorial.My problem is that the users are displayed but the loading page still displayed forever. here is my class:
ListUserActivity.java

```
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ListUsersActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_users);

        showSpinner();
        Log.v("ListUserActivity", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().toString());
        logoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);
        logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageService.class));
                ParseUser.logOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChatActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
    //display clickable a list of all users
    private void setConversationsList() {
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        names = new ArrayList<String>();

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", currentUserId);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
                        names.add(userList.get(i).getUsername().toString());
                    }

                    usersListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
                    namesArrayAdapter =
                            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                                    R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                            openConversation(names, i);
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    //open a conversation with one person
    public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("username", names.get(pos));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> user, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MensajeriaActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            getString(R.string.error_find_user),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    //show a loading spinner while the sinch client starts
    private void showSpinner() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.progress_dialog));
        progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.progress_dialog_message));
        progressDialog.show();

        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Boolean success = intent.getBooleanExtra("success", false);

                progressDialog.dismiss();
                if (!success) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.error_list_users), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("com.example.paul.mapasxavo.ListUsersActivity"));
        Log.v("ShowSpinner-OnReceive", getIntent().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list_users, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        setConversationsList();
        super.onResume();
    }

}
```

The progressDialog.dismiss() is never launched, what am I doning wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may also happen because the broadcast intent is sent before that  the broadcastReceiver is registered. Consequently, the intent is removed by the Garbage Collector then the BroadcastReceiver doesn't receive anything and the spinner is loading indefinitely.

To solve this, ListUsersActivity should be started before MessageService inside LoginActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListUsersActivity.class);
    serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageService.class);

    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    signUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupButton);
    usernameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginUsername);
    passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            username = usernameField.getText().toString();
            password = passwordField.getText().toString();

            ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                        startService(serviceIntent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Wrong username/password combo",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    signUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            username = usernameField.getText().toString();
            password = passwordField.getText().toString();

            ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
            user.setUsername(username);
            user.setPassword(password);

            user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                        startService(serviceIntent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "There was an error signing up."
                                , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it, the problem is that my manifest.xml doesn't have the service:

```
<service android:name=".MessageService"></service>
```

now it works, sorry for the problems

Comment: Maha's response is more correct. Can you mark it as answered?

Comment: How i could mark it as answered ?. Sorry for the silly question

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow